# Remove <a> tag from rails "link_to" methdo

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I need to remove `<a>` tag from rails `link_to` method. Here is current code and result:

```
<%= link_to "ESP", :locale=>'es'%>
<a href="/es/blog/crazy_page">ESP</p>
```

Here is my desired outcome:

```
/es/blog/crazy_page
```

Reason I need this is so I could make "alternate" link tag in header for each language. Can't seem to find this anywhere.

Comment: If you remove the `<a>` tag then the link will no longer be a link... Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `url_for` method

```
<%= url_for(:locale => 'es') %>
```